# Calculate the Gain of a fixed-point filter

Tags: filters, transfer-function, fixed-point

As the title already says, I would like to know how to calculate the Gain and Phase of a given fixed-point filter at a given frequency.

**What I've achieved so far:**
Let's say for example that I have a filter with the following difference equation, which corresponds to a Direct Form I biquad structure:
$$
y[k] = b_0 \cdot x[k] + b_1 \cdot x[k-1] + b_2 \cdot x[k-2] + a_1 \cdot y[k-1] + a_2 \cdot y[k-2]
$$
From this difference equation, I can set up the transfer function in the z-Domain, which is:
$$
H(z) = \frac{b_1 \cdot z^2 + b_2 \cdot z + b_3}{z^2 - a_1 \cdot z - a_2}
$$
To turn this back into frequency-domain, I will simply substitute $z$ with $e^{2 \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{f}{f_s}}$, which will give me $H(f)$.

Finally, I can calculate my filter gain by evaluating my function $H(f)$ at the frequency $f$ of interest (assuming the sampling frequency $f_s$ and all coefficients $a_x,b_x$ are known).

The filter gain $G(f)$ is then:
$$
G(f) = \sqrt{Re(H(f))^2 + Im(H(f))^2}
$$
And the phase $\varphi(f)$ of the filter is:
$$
\varphi(f) = atan2(Im(H(f)), Re(H(f)))
$$

If multiple stages are cascaded together, then
$$
G_{tot} = G_1(f) \cdot G_2(f) \cdot ...
$$
and
$$
\varphi_{tot} = \varphi_1(f) + \varphi_2(f) + ...
$$

**Where I currently get stuck:**
The above equations have all well worked for double-precision filters.
Now, I would like to do the same calculation for a fixed-point (e.g. 1.15) filter that has fixed-point coefficients, a fixed-point input, a fixed-point output and of course also fixed-point multipliers and adders.
What I don't know is how to deal with these constraints during the calculation.

Do I have to truncate the $e^{2 \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{f}{f_s}}$ terms to the specific fixed-point input precision?

Do I have to use the precision formats of my adders and multipliers to calculate the numerators and denumerators in $H(f)$?

How do I treat the division in $H(f)$, the square root in $G(f)$ and the atan2 in $\varphi(f)$?

Do I have to truncate the final value of $H(f)$ to the specific fixed-point output precision? And if yes, what if an overflow happens?

Any clarifying explanation, literature, video etc. is very welcome, since I haven't found anything valuable by googling. However, I am quite a newbie and might have used the wrong terms for my problem explanation.

Thank you so far @Dan Boschen for your help!

**Edit: Where does the gain difference come from???**
This afternoon, I was playing around with a fixed-point filter design and simulation in matlab.
I currently try to implement an Order 4 Butterworth Lowpass filter on a microcontroller by using the ARM-CMSIS-DSP Library [Documentation](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__BiquadCascadeDF1.html#ga4e7dad0ee6949005909fd4fcf1249b79) (Function arm_biquad_cascade_df1_fast_q15).
This function uses the difference equation that I have previously introduced.

What bothers me is, that the settling value of an input step differs from the value that I would expect when looking at the Bode Plot of my filter and I can't explain why.

This is the Bode Plot of my filter:
[image]
The filter has it's expected properties ($f_s$ = 1.2MHz, $f_c$ = 30kHz) and behaves similar to my "initial" double-precision filter.

If I zoom in, you can see, that the DC-Gain of my fixed-point filter is a little bit higher than 1 (1.0012), which OK.
[image]

If I however apply a 0.5 step to my signal, I get an output that settles to a value that is lower than 0.5 (from the step response settling value, the DC-Gain is 0.9738).
[image: Step response]

Even if the gain difference is not very big, I still would like to know where it comes from and why.

This is the matlab code that I used to calculate, simulate and plot everything.

```
clc; clear;

%% Calculate filter coefficients

fs = 1200e3;     %Sampling frequency [Hz]
fc = 30e3;      %Butterworth filter cuttoff frequency [Hz]
n = 4;          %Butterworth filter order

%Get low-pass butterworth filter zeroes and poles
[z, p, g] = butter(n, 2 * fc / fs, 'low');

%Convert zeroes and poles into SOS coefficients
sos_matrix = zp2sos(z, p, g, 'down', 'two');

nCascadedFilterSections = length(sos_matrix(:,1));

%Get double-precision filter coefficients according to my difference equation
%Note: The a coefficients must be multiplied by -1 because matlab uses a
%different difference equation than the CMSIS-Standard
b0_double =  sos_matrix(:, 1);
b1_double =  sos_matrix(:, 2);
b2_double =  sos_matrix(:, 3);
a1_double = -sos_matrix(:, 5);
a2_double = -sos_matrix(:, 6);


%Calculate the required post shift bit to scale all coefficients to my
%fixed-point range [-1 1)
maxValInSos = max(abs(sos_matrix(abs(sos_matrix) > 1)));

if (isempty(maxValInSos))
    postShift = 0;
else
    postShift = ceil(-log2(1 / maxValInSos));
end


%Get 1.15 signed [-1,1) format fixed-point coefficients by truncating the
%scaled double-precision values. Assign previously defined math properties to each
%variable
b0_fixed = fi(b0_double * 2^-postShift, true, 16, 15, fimath('RoundingMethod', 'Nearest'));
b1_fixed = fi(b1_double * 2^-postShift, true, 16, 15, fimath('RoundingMethod', 'Nearest'));
b2_fixed = fi(b2_double * 2^-postShift, true, 16, 15, fimath('RoundingMethod', 'Nearest'));
a1_fixed = fi(a1_double * 2^-postShift, true, 16, 15, fimath('RoundingMethod', 'Nearest'));
a2_fixed = fi(a2_double * 2^-postShift, true, 16, 15, fimath('RoundingMethod', 'Nearest'));

%% Calculate transfer function

%Anonymous Filter Transfer-Function
H = @(z, b0, b1, b2, a1, a2) ((b0 .* z.^2 + b1 .* z + b2) ./ (z.^2 - a1 .* z - a2));

f = 0 : 1 : fs / 2 - 1; %Frequency vector [Hz]
z = exp(1i * 2 * pi * f ./ fs); %Calculate frequency-corresponding z vector

%Calculate double-precision filter gain [-] and phase [°]
mag_double = 1;
ph_double = 0;

for (section = 1 : nCascadedFilterSections)
    mag_double = mag_double .* abs(H(z, ...
        b0_double(section), ...
        b1_double(section), ...
        b2_double(section), ...
        a1_double(section), ...
        a2_double(section)));
    
    ph_double = ph_double + rad2deg(unwrap(angle(H(z, ...
        b0_double(section), ...
        b1_double(section), ...
        b2_double(section), ...
        a1_double(section), ...
        a2_double(section)))));
end

%Calculate fixed-point filter gain [] and phase [°]
%Cast fixed-point variable type back to double (the coefficient value stays
%the same!)
%Multiply variables by postShift value (see CMSIS Documentation)
mag_fixed = 1;
ph_fixed = 0;

for (section = 1 : nCascadedFilterSections)
    mag_fixed = mag_fixed .* abs(H(z, ...
        double(b0_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift, ...
        double(b1_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift, ...
        double(b2_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift, ...
        double(a1_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift, ...
        double(a2_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift));
    
    ph_fixed = ph_fixed + rad2deg(unwrap(angle(H(z, ...
        double(b0_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift, ...
        double(b1_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift, ...
        double(b2_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift, ...
        double(a1_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift, ...
        double(a2_fixed(section)) * 2^postShift))));
end

%Plot
figure(1)
clf(1)
s2 = subplot(2,1,1);
hold on
plot(f * 1e-3, mag_double)
plot(f * 1e-3, mag_fixed)
xlabel('f [kHz]')
ylabel('Gain [-]')
legend('double', 'fixed')
s1 = subplot(2,1,2);
hold on
plot(f * 1e-3, ph_double)
plot(f * 1e-3, ph_fixed)
xlabel('f [kHz]')
ylabel('Phase [°]')
legend('double', 'fixed')
sgtitle('Bode Plot')

linkaxes([s1, s2], "x");
%% Calculate the step response
t = 0: 1 / fs : 1e-3; %Discrete Time vector [s]

stepHight = 0.5; %Height of the step input [-]
step = [zeros(1,20), stepHight * ones(1,length(t) - 20)]; %Step signal

%Define fixed-point math rules according to my arithmetic precisions
%ARM CMSIS-DSP Library:
%https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__BiquadCascadeDF1.html#ga4e7dad0ee6949005909fd4fcf1249b79
%Filter function:
%arm_biquad_cascade_df1_fast_q15()
fixedPointFilterProperties = fimath('CastBeforeSum', true, ...
    'OverflowAction', 'Wrap', ...
    'RoundingMethod', 'Floor', ...
    'ProductWordLength', 32, ...
    'ProductFractionLength', 30, ...
    'ProductMode', 'SpecifyPrecision', ...
    'SumWordLength', 32, ...
    'SumFractionLength', 30, ...
    'SumMode', 'SpecifyPrecision');

%Set fixed point filter properties to coefficients for correct arithmetics
%according to CMSIS
b0_fixed = setfimath(b0_fixed, fixedPointFilterProperties);
b1_fixed = setfimath(b1_fixed, fixedPointFilterProperties);
b2_fixed = setfimath(b2_fixed, fixedPointFilterProperties);
a1_fixed = setfimath(a1_fixed, fixedPointFilterProperties);
a2_fixed = setfimath(a2_fixed, fixedPointFilterProperties);

%Set step signal as input
in = fi(step, true, 16, 15, fixedPointFilterProperties);

%Define fixed-point filter output vector
out = fi(zeros(1, length(in)), true, 16, 15, fixedPointFilterProperties);

%Filter as it would be done by the CMSIS Library function
for (section = 1 : nCascadedFilterSections)
    for (i = 1 : length(in))
        if (i == 1)
            b0_prod = in(i)    * b0_fixed(section);
            b1_prod = 0        * b1_fixed(section);
            b2_prod = 0        * b2_fixed(section);
            a1_prod = 0        * a1_fixed(section);
            a2_prod = 0        * a2_fixed(section);
        elseif (i == 2)
            b0_prod = in(i)    * b0_fixed(section);
            b1_prod = in(i-1)  * b1_fixed(section);
            b2_prod = 0        * b2_fixed(section);
            a1_prod = out(i-1) * a1_fixed(section);
            a2_prod = 0        * a2_fixed(section);
        else
            b0_prod = in(i)    * b0_fixed(section);
            b1_prod = in(i-1)  * b1_fixed(section);
            b2_prod = in(i-2)  * b2_fixed(section);
            a1_prod = out(i-1) * a1_fixed(section);
            a2_prod = out(i-2) * a2_fixed(section);
        end
        accum = b0_prod + b1_prod + b2_prod + a1_prod + a2_prod;
        
        accum = accum * 2^postShift;
        
        out(i) = fi(accum, true, 16, 15, fimath('OverflowAction', 'Saturate', 'RoundingMethod', 'Floor'));
    end
    in = out;
end

%Plot step response
figure(2)
clf(2)
hold on
plot(t,fi(step, true, 16, 15, fixedPointFilterProperties))
plot(t, double(out))
xlabel('t [s]')
ylabel('Response')
legend('original', 'fp filter out')
title('Step response')

%Display DC-Gain of Bode-Plot and Step-Response settling value
DC_Gain_FP_Tf = mag_fixed(1)
DC_Gain_FP_Step = double(out(end)) / stepHight
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice job thus far.

It's really quite simple: Do not change anything with the approach with regards to using $e^{j2\pi f/ f_s}$ to determine the magnitude and phase. The effect of fixed point is to quantize the coefficients in the polynomial only, and then proceed exactly as before. The frequency response itself is still computed as a continuous function along the unit circle, but the result will be effected by the quantization of the polynomial coefficients.  Given the resulting polynomial as $H(z)$, proceed exactly as the math dictates with $z=e^{j\omega}$ with $\omega = 2\pi f/f_s$, which is $H(e^{j\omega})$, a continuous function over $\omega$.

The effect of quantization of the data is quantization noise but otherwise has no impact on the frequency response. The only thing affecting the frequency response is the quantization of the coefficients. A typical rule of thumb is 5 to 6 dB of achievable stop-band rejection per bit of coefficient quantization, and for that in then makes sense to use at least 2 bits higher precision for coefficient quantization over the datapath quantization.

I demonstrate this below with an example of a linear phase filter with a peak stopband rejection of 75 dB with floating point precision, compared to 16 bit coefficient quantization (no discernable difference):

[image: 16 bits]

I then reduced the coefficients to 8 bits and repeated the magnitude frequency response:

[image: 8 bits]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I have played around with some filter designs this afternoon and came to a weird behaviour regarding the calculated Gain from the quantized filter (as you described) and the DC-Gain I get from a simulated step response as outlined in my edited post. Any ideas where the difference comes from?

Comment: ok I will post my follow-up question separately and close this one as answered